# Angular Translate doesn't sanitize models

Tags: angularjs, security, angular-translate

I'm using Angular Translate (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and I've noticed that when the model binding in the view is scoped into a `translate` attribute, the result is not sanitized anymore:

`<p translate>{{Main.BAZ}}</p>`

It means that models from a controller or a component that has malicious code can execute on the page.

I've created a small Plunker to reproduce the issue:
https://plnkr.co/edit/DmITGx77EmsIgEBoWk9R?p=preview

Is that normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Check your console: it should tell you that you haven't set any sanitization strategy: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security. Beware that, if you choose to escape/sanitize the translate values **all** attributes, recursively, will be escaped/sanitized. That can break stuff (like if you store moment objects in the translate values, for example)

Comment: I included the sanitize service already, using `ngSanitize`. The thing is that all variables are sanitized but they aren't when scoped into a `translate` attr.

Comment: You need to be clearer than that. Tell which strategy you used and post the code used to set it, post the code using translate, the content of the relevant key, parameters, translations, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: I did it, please look at the plunker. The first sentence is parsed and the malicious code is executed within the page. The second is not and you can see the malicious code escaped. I wondered why when inside the `translate` attribute, the code isn't escaped. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you actually try to translate a message, using a key which has a value for the current language? Does that work? Because having keys as HTML is quite strange and unusual.

Comment: Yes! I just tried. The malicious code is sanitized. So if it's coming from a translated key and if the key value has some malicious code then the code isn't executed. It looks like it's only executed if the key isn't a key found in the translation keys json.

Comment: I have updated the Plunker for you with the example you requested, thanks.